# Android Studio gives a warning about JDK location

Tags: android, linux, android-studio, ubuntu, gradle

Android Studio 3.6 displays the following warning after Gradle sync completes:

```
15:51   Gradle sync finished in 27 s 97 ms

15:51   Android Studio is using the following JDK location when running Gradle:
                /home/azabost/java/jdk8u252-b09
                Using different JDK locations on different processes might cause Gradle to
                spawn multiple daemons, for example, by executing Gradle tasks from a terminal
                while using Android Studio.
```

I have no clue why I see it and if it makes any sense. The projects build normally with no issues whatsoever. I'm on a fresh Ubuntu system where I installed AdoptOpenJDK to `/home/azabost/java/jdk8u252-b09` and Android Studio 3.6 to `/home/azabost/bin/android-studio-3.6`. I exported several JDK related paths: `JAVA_HOME`, `JDK_HOME` and `STUDIO_JDK` to make sure Android Studio can pick up my JDK properly. Below are the outputs of a few commands showing the proper JDK location:

```
$ which java
/home/azabost/java/jdk8u252-b09/bin/java
```

```
$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_252"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 1.8.0_252-b09)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 25.252-b09, mixed mode)
```

```
$ export | grep java
JAVA_HOME=/home/azabost/java/jdk8u252-b09
JDK_HOME=/home/azabost/java/jdk8u252-b09
PATH=/home/azabost/bin:/home/azabost/java/jdk8u252-b09/bin:/home/azabost/bin/android-sdk/platform-tools:/home/azabost/bin/android-sdk/emulator:/home/azabost/bin/android-sdk/cmdline-tools/latest/bin:/home/azabost/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
STUDIO_JDK=/home/azabost/java/jdk8u252-b09
```

```
./gradlew --version

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 6.3
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2020-03-24 19:52:07 UTC
Revision:     bacd40b727b0130eeac8855ae3f9fd9a0b207c60

Kotlin:       1.3.70
Groovy:       2.5.10
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.7 compiled on September 1 2019
JVM:          1.8.0_252 (AdoptOpenJDK 25.252-b09)
OS:           Linux 5.4.0-28-generic amd64
```

When I open the Project Stucture dialog in Android Studio I can see the proper JDK is set. But when I click the drop-down menu to select a different JDK, I can see something strange. There are 2 options:

1. Embedded JDK: /home/azabost/bin/android-studio-3.6/jre
2. JAVA_HOME: /home/azabost/bin/android-studio-3.6/jre

So the embedded JDK is listed **twice**, including the one with "JAVA_HOME" description which is weird because, as you could see, my `JAVA_HOME` variable points to another JDK.
I'm not sure if this particular list issue is related to the warning I see.

And this is what I see in `~/.AndroidStudio3.6/config/options/jdk.table.xml` file:

```
cat ~/.AndroidStudio3.6/config/options/jdk.table.xml
<application>
  <component name="ProjectJdkTable">
    <jdk version="2">
      <name value="1.8" />
      <type value="JavaSDK" />
      <version value="java version &quot;1.8.0_252&quot;" />
      <homePath value="$USER_HOME$/java/jdk8u252-b09" />
      <roots>
        <annotationsPath>
          <root type="composite">
            <root url="jar://$APPLICATION_HOME_DIR$/plugins/java/lib/jdkAnnotations.jar!/" type="simple" />
          </root>
        </annotationsPath>
        <classPath>
          <root type="composite">
            <root url="jar://$USER_HOME$/java/jdk8u252-b09/jre/lib/charsets.jar!/" type="simple" />
            <root url="jar://$USER_HOME$/java/jdk8u252-b09/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar!/" type="simple" />
            <root url="jar://$USER_HOME$/java/jdk8u252-b09/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar!/" type="simple" />
            <root url="jar://$USER_HOME$/java/jdk8u252-b09/jre/lib/ext/jaccess.jar!/" type="simple" />
            <root url="jar://$USER_HOME$/java/jdk8u252-b09/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar!/" type="simple" />
            <root url="jar://$USER_HOME$/java/jdk8u252-b09/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar!/" type="simple" />
            <root url="jar://$USER_HOME$/java/jdk8u252-b09/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar!/" type="simple" />
            <root url="jar://$USER_HOME$/java/jdk8u252-b09/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar!/" type="simple" />
            <root url="jar://$USER_HOME$/java/jdk8u252-b09/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar!/" type="simple" />
            <root url="jar://$USER_HOME$/java/jdk8u252-b09/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar!/" type="simple" />
            <root url="jar://$USER_HOME$/java/jdk8u252-b09/jre/lib/jce.jar!/" type="simple" />
            <root url="jar://$USER_HOME$/java/jdk8u252-b09/jre/lib/jsse.jar!/" type="simple" />
            <root url="jar://$USER_HOME$/java/jdk8u252-b09/jre/lib/management-agent.jar!/" type="simple" />
            <root url="jar://$USER_HOME$/java/jdk8u252-b09/jre/lib/resources.jar!/" type="simple" />
            <root url="jar://$USER_HOME$/java/jdk8u252-b09/jre/lib/rt.jar!/" type="simple" />
          </root>
        </classPath>
        <javadocPath>
          <root type="composite" />
        </javadocPath>
        <sourcePath>
          <root type="composite">
            <root url="jar://$USER_HOME$/java/jdk8u252-b09/src.zip!/" type="simple" />
          </root>
        </sourcePath>
      </roots>
      <additional />
    </jdk>
    <jdk version="2">
      <name value="Android API 29 Platform" />
      <type value="Android SDK" />
      <version value="java version &quot;1.8.0_252&quot;" />
      <homePath value="$USER_HOME$/bin/android-sdk" />
      <roots>
        <annotationsPath>
          <root type="composite">
            <root url="jar://$APPLICATION_HOME_DIR$/plugins/android/lib/androidAnnotations.jar!/" type="simple" />
          </root>
        </annotationsPath>
        <classPath>
          <root type="composite">
            <root url="jar://$USER_HOME$/bin/android-sdk/platforms/android-29/android.jar!/" type="simple" />
            <root url="file://$USER_HOME$/bin/android-sdk/platforms/android-29/data/res" type="simple" />
          </root>
        </classPath>
        <javadocPath>
          <root type="composite" />
        </javadocPath>
        <sourcePath>
          <root type="composite">
            <root url="file://$USER_HOME$/bin/android-sdk/sources/android-29" type="simple" />
          </root>
        </sourcePath>
      </roots>
      <additional jdk="1.8" sdk="android-29" />
    </jdk>
    <jdk version="2">
      <name value="Kotlin SDK" />
      <type value="KotlinSDK" />
      <homePath value="$KOTLIN_BUNDLED$" />
      <roots>
        <annotationsPath>
          <root type="composite" />
        </annotationsPath>
        <classPath>
          <root type="composite" />
        </classPath>
        <javadocPath>
          <root type="composite" />
        </javadocPath>
        <sourcePath>
          <root type="composite" />
        </sourcePath>
      </roots>
      <additional />
    </jdk>
    <jdk version="2">
      <name value="1.8 (2)" />
      <type value="JavaSDK" />
      <version value="java version &quot;1.8.0_212&quot;" />
      <homePath value="$APPLICATION_HOME_DIR$/jre" />
      <roots>
        <annotationsPath>
          <root type="composite">
            <root url="jar://$APPLICATION_HOME_DIR$/plugins/java/lib/jdkAnnotations.jar!/" type="simple" />
          </root>
        </annotationsPath>
        <classPath>
          <root type="composite">
            <root url="jar://$APPLICATION_HOME_DIR$/jre/jre/lib/charsets.jar!/" type="simple" />
            <root url="jar://$APPLICATION_HOME_DIR$/jre/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar!/" type="simple" />
            <root url="jar://$APPLICATION_HOME_DIR$/jre/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar!/" type="simple" />
            <root url="jar://$APPLICATION_HOME_DIR$/jre/jre/lib/ext/jaccess.jar!/" type="simple" />
            <root url="jar://$APPLICATION_HOME_DIR$/jre/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar!/" type="simple" />
            <root url="jar://$APPLICATION_HOME_DIR$/jre/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar!/" type="simple" />
            <root url="jar://$APPLICATION_HOME_DIR$/jre/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar!/" type="simple" />
            <root url="jar://$APPLICATION_HOME_DIR$/jre/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar!/" type="simple" />
            <root url="jar://$APPLICATION_HOME_DIR$/jre/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar!/" type="simple" />
            <root url="jar://$APPLICATION_HOME_DIR$/jre/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar!/" type="simple" />
            <root url="jar://$APPLICATION_HOME_DIR$/jre/jre/lib/jce.jar!/" type="simple" />
            <root url="jar://$APPLICATION_HOME_DIR$/jre/jre/lib/jsse.jar!/" type="simple" />
            <root url="jar://$APPLICATION_HOME_DIR$/jre/jre/lib/management-agent.jar!/" type="simple" />
            <root url="jar://$APPLICATION_HOME_DIR$/jre/jre/lib/resources.jar!/" type="simple" />
            <root url="jar://$APPLICATION_HOME_DIR$/jre/jre/lib/rt.jar!/" type="simple" />
          </root>
        </classPath>
        <javadocPath>
          <root type="composite">
            <root url="https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/" type="simple" />
          </root>
        </javadocPath>
        <sourcePath>
          <root type="composite" />
        </sourcePath>
      </roots>
      <additional />
    </jdk>
    <jdk version="2">
      <name value="Android API 28 Platform" />
      <type value="Android SDK" />
      <version value="java version &quot;1.8.0_212&quot;" />
      <homePath value="$USER_HOME$/bin/android-sdk" />
      <roots>
        <annotationsPath>
          <root type="composite">
            <root url="jar://$USER_HOME$/bin/android-sdk/platforms/android-28/data/annotations.zip!/" type="simple" />
          </root>
        </annotationsPath>
        <classPath>
          <root type="composite">
            <root url="jar://$USER_HOME$/bin/android-sdk/platforms/android-28/android.jar!/" type="simple" />
            <root url="file://$USER_HOME$/bin/android-sdk/platforms/android-28/data/res" type="simple" />
          </root>
        </classPath>
        <javadocPath>
          <root type="composite" />
        </javadocPath>
        <sourcePath>
          <root type="composite">
            <root url="file://$USER_HOME$/bin/android-sdk/sources/android-28" type="simple" />
          </root>
        </sourcePath>
      </roots>
      <additional jdk="1.8 (2)" sdk="android-28" />
    </jdk>
  </component>
</application>%
```

And according to `ps -x` Android Studio launched using the embedded JDK:

```
ps -x | grep studio
  28805 ?        S      0:00 /bin/sh /home/azabost/bin/android-studio-3.6/bin/studio.sh
  28908 ?        Sl     5:06 /home/azabost/bin/android-studio-3.6/jre/bin/java -classpath /home/azabost/bin/android-studio-3.6/lib/bootstrap.jar:/home/azabost/bin/android-studio-3.6/lib/extensions.jar:/home/azabost/bin/android-studio-3.6/lib/util.jar:/home/azabost/bin/android-studio-3.6/lib/jdom.jar:/home/azabost/bin/android-studio-3.6/lib/log4j.jar:/home/azabost/bin/android-studio-3.6/lib/trove4j.jar:/home/azabost/bin/android-studio-3.6/lib/jna.jar:/home/azabost/bin/android-studio-3.6/jre/lib/tools.jar -Xms256m -Xmx1280m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50 -XX:CICompilerCount=2 -Dsun.io.useCanonPrefixCache=false -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes="" -Djdk.attach.allowAttachSelf -Dkotlinx.coroutines.debug=off -Djdk.module.illegalAccess.silent=true -Djna.nosys=true -Djna.boot.library.path= -da -Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=lcd -Dsun.java2d.renderer=sun.java2d.marlin.MarlinRenderingEngine -Dsun.tools.attach.tmp.only=true -Xmx3072m -XX:ErrorFile=/home/azabost/java_error_in_STUDIO_%p.log -XX:HeapDumpPath=/home/azabost/java_error_in_STUDIO.hprof -Didea.paths.selector=AndroidStudio3.6 -Djb.vmOptionsFile=/home/azabost/bin/android-studio-3.6/bin/studio64.vmoptions,/home/azabost/.AndroidStudio3.6/config/studio64.vmoptions -Didea.platform.prefix=AndroidStudio -Didea.jre.check=true com.intellij.idea.Main
```

Answer (score 0):

The error clearly saying that you have installed android studio in java directory. Its saying change the location. U can give other drive path to installed the studio. download the upgraded version of java from 1.8 https://www.oracle.com/in/java/technologies/javase-downloads.html
Also change your path from the existing directory.

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand your point. What do you mean by saying "you have installed android studio in java directory"? I clearly described all my paths which seem valid. Also, I have the latest Java 8 from the AdoptOpenJDK site and I'm not going to use the Oracle's.